# I want to raise an event ,when user opens a google form?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

but according to google app script doc, open() event is only enabled for editor mode,is there any other way so I can create a custom trigger for google forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an HTML interface where you would embed the form and publish the script as a web app. In the HTML of the web app you would then tell it to call a function using `google.script.run` on page load.

Answer (score 1):

The onOpen event is only available for documents and spreadsheet. You can only create a submit event with Google Forms that is trigger when someone submits a form.